# mybatis list foreach is null

Tags: java, sql, spring, mybatis

I've already determined in the java code that the list is not empty before executing the sql, but occasionally there are sql's here that are wrong.

Sometimes the production sql is

```
select name from user where id in
```

Service.java      ObjectUtils is org.apache.commons.lang3.ObjectUtils

I know can't add directly in parallelStream, should use Collectors.toSet.

What I'd like to know is that this error sql is related to list.parallelStream

```
public List<String> queryByIds() {
    Set<Long> ids = new HashSet<>();
    list.parallelStream().forEach(obj -> {
       ids.add(obj.id)
    }

    if (ObjectUtils.isEmpty(ids)){
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
    return mapper.queryByIds(ids);
}
```

mapper.java

```
List<String> queryByIds(@Param("list") Set<Long> ids);
```

mapper.xml

```
<select id="queryByIds" resultType="java.lang.String">
    select name from user where id in
    <foreach collection="list" item="item" index="index" open="(" separator="," close=")">
        #{item}
    </foreach>
</select>
```

Comment: Now, what do you want to do when the list is empty? Return the entire table, no rows at all, something else? A simple `<if test="list.size == 0">` can produce the behavior you want.

Comment: @TheImpaler I know this solution, but now I want to know, why there will be error sql, because I have already judged the empty in the java code.

Comment: @TheImpaler I know the answer, because parallelStream makes the size different from the real length of the collection.

Comment: I fail to understand your question. You say "...Sometimes the production sql is..."; well, that's not a valid SQL statement and will crash your application. What do you need?